# Could not find a version that satysfies the requirement pytz

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-18.04

i have Linux Ubuntu 18.04. I need to install Django offline on this machine.

I had some problems with pip and python, but i guess i solved it. So, i download asgiref, sqlparse and pytz for installing modules. When i install asgiref and sqlparse - it's ok, django see it, but with pytz, i have a terrible problems: django doesn't see it, andi try reinstall it a lot of time. I try to use 
`python3.7 -m pip install --pre pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
but it doesn't help. So in    `python3.7 -m pip list` it shows, that pytz install, but actually i can't to delete it.

Finally, when i try (in folder with fjango installer)

```
python37 -m pip install .
```

I have this error

[image]
    Couldt not find a version that satysfies the requirement pytz

```
python3.7 -m pip freeze
```

```html
apturl==0.5.2
asgiref==3.2.7
asn1crypto==0.24.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.6.6
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==2.1.4
cupshelpers==1.0
defer==1.0.6
distro-info===0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
Django==3.0.4
feedparser==5.2.1
html5lib==0.999999999
httplib2==0.9.2
idna==2.6
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.6
lazr.restfulclient==0.13.5
lazr.uri==1.0.3
louis==3.5.0
lxml==4.2.1
macaroonbakery==1.1.3
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
netifaces==0.10.4
oauth==1.0.1
oauthlib==2.0.6
onboard==1.4.1
protobuf==3.0.0
pycairo==1.16.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
pygobject==3.26.1
PyJWT==1.5.3
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.1.2
pyRFC3339==1.0
python-apt==1.6.5+ubuntu0.2
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-debian==0.1.32
pytz==2020.1
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.4
requests-unixsocket==0.1.5
SecretStorage==2.3.1
simplejson==3.13.2
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
unity-scope-calculator==0.1
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-colourlovers==0.1
unity-scope-devhelp==0.1
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-manpages==0.1
unity-scope-openclipart==0.1
unity-scope-texdoc==0.1
unity-scope-tomboy==0.1
unity-scope-virtualbox==0.1
unity-scope-yelp==0.1
unity-scope-zotero==0.1
urllib3==1.22
usb-creator==0.3.3
wadllib==1.3.2
webencodings==0.5
xdiagnose==3.8.8
xkit==0.0.0
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Comment: Did you try installing the `.whl` file for Django too? https://pypi.org/project/Django/#files

Comment: Thank you, for answer.

Yes, i try it just now, but i have same problem. Actually i try to install Django this way on different Linux machines, and i had successful installed it, but here i have problems. And else i try to install a new version of python and pip on this machine - it doesn't help. In both version it have same errors.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `python3.7 -m pip freeze` command?

Comment: Yes, i added this.

Comment: It looks like Django is already installed.

Comment: Yeah, it's really fantastic. Only in folder with installer (in other it write django module not find) i can create new project, it is really strange, But when i try `python3.7 manage.py runservers` it send error  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`